# Orchard cms token json

Tags: orchardcms

I would like to format a json payload in a workflow activity. I use the new {Text.JavaScriptEncode} to enclose my properties in {}. I should do it wrong because the tokens are not evaluated anymore.  So if i use

```
{Text.JavaScriptEncode}{
"Courriel":{FormSubmission.Field:Courriel}
{Text.JavaScriptEncode}}
```

It ends with the following value:

```
{
"Courriel":{FormSubmission.Field:Courriel}
}
```

So the {FormSubmission.Field:Courriel} is not evaluated.  If i don't specify {Text.JavaScriptEncode} before the first {, nothing is rendered (empty string).

I'm using Orchard 1.10.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to turn on the [Tokenizers HashMode](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/1.10.x/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Tokens/Implementation/Tokenizer.cs#L49).

I haven't tested your token but I'm pretty sure the tokenizer tries to evaluate
this as a token and fails:

```
{"Courriel":{FormSubmission.Field:Courriel}
```

With hashMode enabled your code will look like this:

```
#{Text.JavaScriptEncode}{
"Courriel":#{FormSubmission.Field:Courriel}
#{Text.JavaScriptEncode}}
```